# possible solutions for EADDRINUSE (Address already in use) issue

Tags: android, sockets, serversocket, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have set up wifi direct for communication between two apps in two android devices. This works fine when there is only one activity in both the apps. When I try to establish a connection from the second activity of any app, I am getting Socket EADDRINUSE (Address already in use) error. This error also happens when I close the app and start it again. But it works when I start the app after killing the previously opened app.

I have tried socket.setReuseAddress(true) but still the error comes.

Owner side:

```
ServerSocket socket = null;
    private final int THREAD_COUNT = 10;
    private Handler handler;

    private final ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
            THREAD_COUNT, THREAD_COUNT, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());

    public OwnerSocketHandler(Handler handler) throws IOException {
        try {
            socket = new ServerSocket();
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Settings.SERVER_PORT));
            this.handler = handler;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            pool.shutdownNow();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                pool.execute(new SocketStream(socket.accept(), handler));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "socket close");
                    if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed())
                        socket.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                pool.shutdownNow();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Member side:

```
   @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        try {
            socket.bind(null);
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address.getHostAddress(), Settings.SERVER_PORT), Settings.TIME_OUT);
            socketCreator = new SocketCreator(socket, handler);
            new Thread(socketCreator).start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

In the SocketStream class, I write/read data using output and input streams.

What should I do to overcome this error in the above mentioned cases? Is there any demo where multiple activities communicate using wifi direct?